# Is our vascular plant alive or not?

Tags: plant-health

We have one vascular plant ([Araucaria heterophylla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araucaria_heterophylla)) which asjed about that it before [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/48957/27703).

So according the answer to the question, i have triyed to change it's soil by this kind:

[image]

And

[image]

[image]

And this GIF :

[image]
<sub>(source: [techpowerup.org](https://img.techpowerup.org/200116/20200113-121140-ic8hkf8ha7.gif))</sub>

So i like to know is this condition enough for curing this plant? And dose it still alve or not?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I hope it will be ok let me know how it is next week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plant needs more light and clean water with no chlorine.
(PH 6.2( is perfect  but a little more or a little less is ok but not (PH 4 or PH 8) like tap water.

Soil must be well draining so the water comes out from the pot quickly.

Good luck